# Is it possible to use multibinding in WF (with ActivityBind)?

Tags: .net, xaml, binding, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I would like to bind multiple dependency properties of other activites to a dependency property (of type `object[]`) in my custom activity. Is it possible to define this multibinding :

- In the workflow markup (probably somehow combining multiple ActivityBind's)
- Set up the property editor in such a way that I can even edit this binding in the workflow designer ?